# How can I map to a structure method?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a structure method as a map target. When I try to reference the method in the map argument simply by 'self.method', I get the error 'method, not a field'.

Here is some simple code to show what I'm trying to do

```
impl Astruc {
    fn map_function(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
        2 * index
    }
    fn map_attempt(&self) {
        (0..10).map(self.map_function)  // this causes the error: method, not a field
    }
}
```

How can I properly reference `map_function`?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5cd12df33bb6c4964e771588d255c08

Comment: That's a cool site.   I forgot it was an instance and added the self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call a method on the instance, a closure can be used instead.

```
fn map_attempt(&self) {
    (0..10).map(|i| self.map_function(i))
        .for_each(|i| println!("{i}"));
}
```

However, if `map_function` does not actually need to be called on an instance, then it can be referred to with the name of the struct or `Self` (after removing the `self` parameter).

```
impl Astruc {
    fn map_function(index: usize) -> usize {
        2 * index
    }
    fn map_attempt(&self) {
        (0..10).map(Self::map_function)
            .for_each(|i| println!("{i}"));
    }
}
```